# Image reloading

Tags: jquery, image

I am reloading the image after upload and showing it in jquery by following code:

```
    $('#profile_pic').empty().append('<img src="'+user.data.thumb+'">');
```

If i do `console.log(user);` it shows the user->data->thumb as new upload url.But if check

this    `console.log(user.data.thumb)` the it show me the previous image url , so due to this my image is not reloaded.
Please Help.

Comment: replacement worked fine for me (i used a string instead of a javascript object) thus the jquery can't be blamed

Comment: @Thariama you mean that i put user.datat.thumb in string variable and then pass the variable in src of image

Comment: You mean console.log(user) shows an object and clicking it to see user.data.thumb shows the new url?

Comment: Ya user is object and clicking it shows the Right url of the image being uploaded now in user.data.thumb